# C# Windows Phone app full screen controls

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I am developing WP 10 application which includes playing videos in full screen mode. When I switch to full screen mode I want to have control buttons (play, stop...) visible on touch (at the moment they are hidden behind the full screen video). I'd appreciate if someone could give me some directions how to do it.

Here is an example of WP 10 official video application control bar. It appears if you tap screen and disappears after a second or two.

[WP10 official video app image][1]

**EDIT:**
Seems like new SDK has built in control bar and it's really simple to use.
Just add Media element attribute

```
AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
```

Comment: you can post it as Answer, and you can vote it as Correct after 2 days and receive the "Self Learner" badge. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like new SDK has built in control bar and it's really simple to use. Just add Media element attribute

```
AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
```